# How to Asynchronously Load Complex Set Filter Values

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I've been reviewing the documentation for how to asynchronously load data for a Set Filter by assigning the `values` filterParam to a function. I have in fact gotten this to work for simple string array as well. However, if I attempt to assign an array of objects then it converts each of those objects to the useless string value "[Object Object]" - not what I want.

```
// Example Complex Type
interface IAmNotJustANumber {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Here is the link to the relevant documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#asynchronous-values

The problem appears to be the params that are passed into the values function - which is of type `SetFilterValuesFuncParams`. The `success` function expects a string[] for its input - and even if I attempt to bypass this by casting the input as an `any` type it internally performs the string conversion.

```
values: (params: SetFilterValuesFuncParams) => {
   loadData().then(response => params.success(response.data as any)); // DOES NOT WORK
}
```

However, in the same documentation Set Filters are said to support Complex Types (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#complex-objects). You just gotta accompany it with KeyCreator and ValueFormatter functions. These functions won't work, however, if I can't set the data properly.

One workaround that I thought of while writing this up is to use `JSON.stringify` to convert each complex object to a string and then deserialize those values in the KeyCreator and ValueFormatter. However, this feels very hacky.

```
filterParams: {
  values: (params) => { 
    loadData().then(response => 
      params.success(response.data.map(d => JSON.stringify(d))
    ) 
  },

  keyCreator: (params) => {
    const v : IAmNotJustANumber = JSON.parse(params.value);
    return v.id;
  },

  valueFormatter: (params) => {
    const v : IAmNotJustANumber = JSON.parse(params.value);
    return `${v.id} [${v.name}]`;
  }
}
```

Is this simply an oversight in the AgGrid implementation? Or is there a better solution that I am missing here? I'm new to the AgGrid library - so any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no other solution right now, the values expect an array of string. We proceeded as you mentioned (stringify and parse JSON) for all our filters.

The other solution could be to store the array of complex objects locally, then using that array for the valueFormatter and cellRenderer functions.

Note: The document is far from perfect on Ag-grid. When they are talking about complex objects in that part of the doc, they're actually talking about complex objects for the column itself, not for the filter values.